# Mark part of code as "it can not be in release"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Is there any method to mark some place it code, which has to be improved? I seen it before somewhere but can not remember now. It blocks release build, and it is not `TODO` comment. What is it?

Comment: You can use a [FixmeComment](http://wiki.c2.com/?FixmeComment). Though it won't break builds AFAIK

Answer (score 2):

I've found. It is StopShip lint check.

Enable it in build.gradle:

```
android {
...
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
        fatal 'StopShip'
    }
}
```

If you have a `//STOPSHIP` comment in your code, this will cause an error to be thrown when a release apk is generated.

You can turn on `//STOPSHIP` highlighting in Android Studio (wasn't enabled by default for me) in Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Inspections. Search for `STOPSHIP` to find the correct setting.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/5c8b0a/i_know_android_studio_allows_you_to_make_custom/d9uhdzt/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a native way provided to do so.

You may however do something like this, by control a single boolean:

```
static boolean isDebug = false;
assert isDebug = true;

if (isDebug)
{
    /* Do stuff only for debug builds */
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.. You will use this to add code which **runs** only on debug builds.. It won't affect release builds at all.  Also Android provides `BuildConfig.DEBUG` for this purpose which is set automatically

Answer (score 0):

We need to use **BuildConfig.DEBUG**

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
{
    /* Do stuff only for debug builds */
}
```

Its the proper way for writing some code only for Debug and no need to use any variables to check for debug as **BuildConfig.DEBUG** its taken care by Android run system depending on your Build Config.